# Parenting teeth to character's face after blendshapes have been created

Tags: animation

I have created a character's face and shapekeys for it. I now want to add some teeth to it. I tried vertex parenting the teeth to the bottom jaw and this worked in Blender, but when I export it as an fbx and import into Unity, the teeth are no longer parented.

Is there some other way I can parent the teeth to the bottom jaw which will transfer to Unity?

Comment: You could simply join the teeth object to the rest of the head, or parent the teeth to the jaw bones if they exist, please tell a bit more about your object, rigging, etc, and maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: HI thanks for the reply. There are no bones, all the animation is done using shape keys. If i simply join the teeth to the head they wont animate with the jaw.

Comment: once you've joined the teeth you need to select the shapekey of the open mouth and move the teeth vertices accordingly, I'm not sure you have any other choice

Comment: ok well thanks very much for the suggestion, i'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have this head model with shapekeys and this teethmodel:

[image]

First, make sure all your shapekeys are set to zero:

[image]

This is so that the teeth are joined into the basis state of the mesh.

Then select the teeth object, then the head, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join the selection into the head object.

Set the open jaw's shapekey to 1, and <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode.

Hover the teeth mesh and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select it. Move it where you want it to be.

[image]

And there you go:

[image]